# Would this experiment bring down the electric grid?

Tags: electric-circuits

A friend reported that they had lost power in about one-half of the circuits in the house.  I noted that it must be the main circuit breaker, since the two lines coming in from the electric meter both tested at 120 volts.  Also, I seemed to recall that the two lines should be exactly out of phase.  (A phase difference of π, as required by a 240 volt motor perhaps?)  So, as I was working on it a bit later, I wondered what would happen if I were to touch those two voltage sources together.  Being of inverse phases, would the electric fields cancel?  My first thought was as to where would the field energy go, but of course, there is no energy, per say, in the wires - only energy potential.  Considering that the forces on a charge at that point of contact would be equal and opposite, they would cancel - amounting to a zero potential.  But of course, the electrical potential in the wires going back up to the transformer would also be zero, and so for any wires continuous with those.  I cannot figure what would happen beyond the transformer, but would my neighbors lose power?  Perhaps this thought experiment is just to conclude that the line volatges are, in fact, not out of phase, but I am curious to see what anyone might have to say.  Thanks!

Comment: The two phases coming into your house are not $\pi$ out of phase - they are $2\pi/3$ out of phase. They are two of the three phases, and you may have heard of wye vs delta three phase systems. And, should you try it, you will likely blow your main breaker and may well be severely harmed and/or killed. Do not try this at home (or anywhere else).

Comment: Wow!  Now I am really intrigued.  I will look those up.  Thanks for the pointer, and the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are forgetting *current*, which begins to flow the instant you touch the wires together. So, shorting together the two legs of your mains supply with a low resistance will suddenly allow a truly gigantic current to flow, converting the resistor into plasma. You'll be essentially holding an arc welder with your hands, which will be fried into wads of burnt meat and set your clothes and hair on fire.

The circuit breaker is supposed to quickly respond to excessive current and disconnect the mains, but if it does not then the lights in the houses served by the same transformer will all suddenly go dim, as the low resistance hogs the power from the transformer.

Meanwhile, the incandescent arc will emit a powerful and terrifying 50 or 60Hz humming noise.

If that transformer is suspended from a pole behind your house you can go outside and see that the wires connecting its primary side to the high voltage wires each are clamped to opposite ends of a short rod which is a fuse made of solid aluminum. A short circuit in the secondary of that transformer will cause so much current to flow through the aluminum fuse that it will explode like a bomb in a shower of sparks and aluminum oxide.

Comment: So firstly, I did knock off the meter outside as a precaution, but I can feel the hair raising on my neck, and perhaps yours as well.  Secondarily, if I am getting this right, there might, indeed - in the hypothetical case in which the phase difference is π, be zero potential between this plasma and the ground, but within it there would still be 240 Volts across the wires.  Thank you for the vivid description.  Knowing that there is such a fuse between the local transformer and the 480V supply gives me a bit of confidence.  One never knows what kind of impetuous kooks that might be out there.